# What should I do about a screw jammed in my deadbolt?

Tags: doors, lock

So, I recently purchased a new house and went about changing the locks. The doorknob worked well, but not so much on the deadbolt. Installed everything but one screw which wouldn't budge. I ended up stripping it, but was able to remove it. Since it was the same model as the old deadbolt, I figure the screws on the old one would work. I ended up jamming the screw and now even a stripped screw extractor bit can't move it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a photo so we can tell which screw is giving you a problem?

Comment: Sometimes, drilling/grinding the head off is the best option available...

Comment: A dremel with a cut off disk can cut a slot that a straight blade screwdriver may be able to back it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try drilling the head of the screw, which will allow you to remove the cover of th lock and use a vise grip to un-tighten the old screw.
Good Luck